# Mercurial-like named branches experience in Perforce

Tags: version-control, mercurial, perforce, branching-and-merging

I am new to Perforce and find it really hard to follow its workflow..

I have used Mercurial before (not in any advanced ways), but what I lack most in Perforce is the idea of named branches.

Let me explain what I'd like to do:

- I get the latest revisions of all files and want to work on a new feature/story/task..
- I create a brach, say "Feature 3021"
- I code, save changes in this branch (hg commit)
- I can save changes to a central server (hg push)
- When I'm done coding, I merge the changes from "Feature 3021" with the main branch (default, master, etc.) - after that the main branch has the code I wrote
- I can close the named brach ("Feature 3021") so that further commits are not possible.

I don't need this exact behavior in Perforce, but something analogous. I know that Perforce is centralized, so the commit-push step would be probably one, but this is a minor problem here.

All I care is to be able to save my work in version control at any time, even if it's not 100% ready - perhaps to a different branch. I'd also like other users to be able to be able to get my code (from this different branch), but only if they want this - the default branch should stay unafected as long as I don't merge my changes with it.

Is it possible? I am using Server 2012.2

Answer (score 1):

Can you upgrade to Server 2013.1 or later? There's a great feature there, called Task Streams.

Here's some references:

http://www.perforce.com/blog/130627/task-streams-even-if-you-are-classic-perforce-shop

http://www.perforce.com/blog/130206/task-streams

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/streams_task.html

Answer (score 1):

The analogous flow in Perforce would be:

- Maintain a main-line "branch" at some path, say `//depot/default`
- To create a feature branch, `integrate` from `//depot/default` to `//depot/feature-3021`
- Work under `//depot/feature-3021` and submit
- When you are ready to merge back, integrate `//depot/feature-3021` to `//depot/default`

Regarding closing the branch after its use, there are a couple of options that I can think of.  You could either change permissions or simply delete it. The delete could always be recovered.

Also note the paths don't need to be at the same hierarchy. A more reasonable branch strategy might use paths like this.

Main-line: `//depot/default`

Developer branches: `//depot/dev/${user}/${feature}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like it. But I am just a regular developer in my company and I am not sure what privileges I have... Do I understand correctly, that the feature depot would have to be created on the central server? Or can I create it there from my machine.. ?

Comment: @KalamarObliwy It depends on the directory structure within the depot and the associated privileges, however you are not created a new depot in this flow. You are only created new files in a different location. That is how branching is done in Perforce.